# I can't reference a dynamic variable

Tags: loops, variables, dynamic, coldfusion, reference

Trying to use dynamic form field names.  I can get them on the page but I can’t reference them to insert or select from a table.  I have done this before with naming the form fields dynamically with numbers and then looping through them to insert data into a table but these items will be inserted into different tables and so I wanted to reference them by name and I’ve tried several options and I get an error on all I’ve tried so far.
What I have on the form is 4 to 6 fields with an Add button for each section.  I want to click the add button and insert the fields to a specific table and I have a table below each section that will then show the data just added.

```
<cfif structKeyExists(form,"Add")>
    <cfquery name = "getTableColumnHeadings">
        SELECT * FROM '#enclTable#'  <<< errors here  >>>  enclTable is undefined
    </cfquery>
    <center><cfdump var = "#enclTable#"></center>   <<<  and here  >>>      enclTable is undefined
</cfif>
```

Form fields (loops from a query to add field’s id, name and maxlen and button’s id)…

```
<cfloop query ="getFormHeadings">
    <cfloop query = "getFormFields">
        <input type="input" class="form-control" id="#inpID#" name="#inpName#" maxlength="#inpLen#">
    </cfloop>
    <button class="btn btn-blue btn-block" type="submit" name="Add"  id="#enclTable#">
</cfloop>
```

The button is in another loop through another query

I tried this too in a loop and incremented the x

```
<cfset variables["encl#x#"] = "#enclTable#">
```

But then when I place it in the

```
<cfif structKeyExists(form,"Add")>
```

I get an error that the x is undefined

```
#variables["enclTable" & x]#
```

didn’t work either.  I’m not sure what I’m doing wrong.  I can create the dynamic variable but I can’t reference it after to do anything with it.  Sorry if this is a lot of explanation, I wanted to be thorough with all the details.

Comment: You are on the right track with the array notation.  But you want the form scope, not the variables scope.

Comment: *enclTable is undefined* Where in the code are you defining a form field or variable named *enclTablexxxx*? I do not see it in the code above, so that error message is not surprising. What is the actual value of `name="#inpName#"`? As an aside, using client supplied values in a query like puts the database at risk for sql injection.

Comment: @leigh, enclTable is coming from the query  getFormHeadings. inpName is coming from the query getFormFields.  enclTable is a name of a table and inpName is a name of a field in that table.  I was trying to reverence what was being held in enclTable to use to insert records into.  The variable inpName is holding the name of the fields and the enclTable is holding the name of the table.  I can't reference them to get the values even after indexing them.  I have another idea I'm going to try along with Dan Bracuk's idea.  Any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated though.  Thanks!

Comment: *enclTable is coming from the query getFormHeadings* @malibu65k - It does not look like that query exists when you are processing the form. That means there is no variable named "enclTable" in scope, which explains the undefined error. *The variable inpName is holding the name of the fields*  No, you are using the VALUE as the field name, ie `name="#inpName#"`. Not the same thing. So again, no variable or form field named "enclTable" exists. Hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I handle that sort of situation.  The form looks like this:

```
<cfoutput query="GetRecords">
<cfinput type="hidden" name="OldSpelling#DrugId#" value="#StandardSpelling#">
<cfinput type="hidden" name="OldInclude#DrugId#" value="#IncludeInReport#">
<cfinput type="hidden" name="OldCategory#DrugId#" value="#CategoryID#">
<tr>
<td>#DrugName#</td>
<td>
```

etc.

The processing looks like this:

```
<cfloop list="#form.fieldnames#" index="ThisField">
<cfscript>
CheckForDifference = false;
if (left(ThisField, 10) == "oldinclude"){
ThisId = RemoveChars(ThisField, 1, 10);
ThisOldInclude = form[ThisField];
ThisInclude = form["Include" & ThisID];
```

and then I do something with those variables.